# How to pull up a form based on matching criteria?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, data-entry

I am currently creating an access database for data entry. As of right now, I have a welcome screen that asks for a participant number and the date that the evaluation was completed. After that, raters will be taken to the next form to fill out the data that was gathered for the participant. Is there a way to have access pull up an already completed form if the participant number and date matches and has already been entered? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

More than one way to accomplish. One approach is to apply filter criteria when opening form. Very simple example:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("fieldname", "tablename", "criteria here")) Then
     DoCmd.OpenForm "form name", , , "criteria here"
Else
     DoCmd.OpenForm "form name", , , , , acFormAdd, "new data here"
End If
```

Also, ways to pass the new data to the opened form and populate fields of new record. One approach is to use OpenArgs argument of OpenForm (the 'new data here' shown in example). And then code behind the second form would pull values from the OpenArgs.

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
     'code to extract data elements from OpenArgs and populate fields
     'or if the opening screen is still open, 
     'just reference controls on that form for the data elements
End If
```

The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into. Keep in mind: 'the more user-friendly, the more code'.

When you develop code you have specific issue with, post it for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

So, just a quick mock-up:

```
Public Sub btnLoadEval_Click()

    Dim ParticipantNumber as String
    Dim EvaluationDate as Date
    Dim EvaluationID as Variant

    If Not IsNull(Me.txtParticipantNumber.Value) And _
       Not IsNull(Me.txtEvaluationDate.Value) Then

        ParticipantNumber = Me.txtParticipantNumber.Value
        EvaluationDate = Me.txtEvaluationDate.Value

        EvaluationID = DLookup("EvaluationID", "Evaluations", _
            "[ParticipantNumber]=""" & ParticipantNumber & _
            """ And [EvaluationDate]=#" & EvaluationDate & "#")

        If Not IsNull(EvaluationID) Then

            Call DoCmd.OpenForm("frmEvaluation",,,"[EvaluationID]=" & _
               EvaluationID

            Call DoCmd.Close(acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo)

        Else

           Call MsgBox("No matching evaluation!")

        End If

    Else

        Call MsgBox("Please enter both fields!")

    End If

End Sub
```